# Handling "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" in JSON POST

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm working on a side project as an opportunity to learn Python and have cobbled together a webscraper that works *most* of the time. Essentially I have a list of ~2,000 items that I iterate over making a separate POST request for each which returns a JSON file with stock and price data.

The issue I am having is that on certain runs there is a random item in my list that returns: "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable". This knocks knocks me out of my for loop and I have to restart the entire process, with no guarantee that it works the next time through. **Is there a way to skip over the items in the list that return this error and keep the script running?**

The most recent error was for this row on roughly the 200th item in the list:

```
price = resp['data']['product']['pricing']['value']
```

Section of code:

```
for store_code in stores_codes:
 for prod in prods:

    query = {
        "operationName":"productClientOnlyProduct","variables":{
            "skipSpecificationGroup":False,"skipSubscribeAndSave":False,"skipKPF":False,"itemId":str(prod),"storeId":str(store_code),"zipCode":"75209" #not sure we need to change zip?
            },
        "query":"query productClientOnlyProduct($storeId: String, $zipCode: String, $itemId: String!, $dataSource: String, $loyaltyMembershipInput: LoyaltyMembershipInput, $skipSpecificationGroup: Boolean = false, $skipSubscribeAndSave: Boolean = false, $skipKPF: Boolean = false) {\n  product(itemId: $itemId, dataSource: $dataSource, loyaltyMembershipInput: $loyaltyMembershipInput) {\n    fulfillment(storeId: $storeId, zipCode: $zipCode) {\n      backordered\n      fulfillmentOptions {\n        type\n        services {\n          type\n          locations {\n            isAnchor\n            inventory {\n              isLimitedQuantity\n              isOutOfStock\n              isInStock\n              quantity\n              isUnavailable\n              maxAllowedBopisQty\n              minAllowedBopisQty\n              __typename\n            }\n            type\n            storeName\n            locationId\n            curbsidePickupFlag\n            isBuyInStoreCheckNearBy\n            distance\n            state\n            storePhone\n            __typename\n          }\n          deliveryTimeline\n          deliveryDates {\n            startDate\n            endDate\n            __typename\n          }\n          deliveryCharge\n          dynamicEta {\n            hours\n            minutes\n            __typename\n          }\n          hasFreeShipping\n          freeDeliveryThreshold\n          totalCharge\n          __typename\n        }\n        fulfillable\n        __typename\n      }\n      anchorStoreStatus\n      anchorStoreStatusType\n      backorderedShipDate\n      bossExcludedShipStates\n      sthExcludedShipState\n      bossExcludedShipState\n      excludedShipStates\n      seasonStatusEligible\n      onlineStoreStatus\n      onlineStoreStatusType\n      inStoreAssemblyEligible\n      __typename\n    }\n    info {\n      dotComColorEligible\n      hidePrice\n      ecoRebate\n      quantityLimit\n      sskMin\n      sskMax\n      unitOfMeasureCoverage\n      wasMaxPriceRange\n      wasMinPriceRange\n      fiscalYear\n      productDepartment\n      classNumber\n      forProfessionalUseOnly\n      globalCustomConfigurator {\n        customButtonText\n        customDescription\n        customExperience\n        customExperienceUrl\n        customTitle\n        __typename\n      }\n      paintBrand\n      movingCalculatorEligible\n      label\n      prop65Warning\n      returnable\n      recommendationFlags {\n        visualNavigation\n        reqItems\n        batItems\n        __typename\n      }\n      replacementOMSID\n      hasSubscription\n      minimumOrderQuantity\n      projectCalculatorEligible\n      subClassNumber\n      calculatorType\n      isLiveGoodsProduct\n      protectionPlanSku\n      hasServiceAddOns\n      consultationType\n      __typename\n    }\n    itemId\n    dataSources\n    identifiers {\n      canonicalUrl\n      brandName\n      itemId\n      modelNumber\n      productLabel\n      storeSkuNumber\n      upcGtin13\n      specialOrderSku\n      toolRentalSkuNumber\n      rentalCategory\n      rentalSubCategory\n      upc\n      productType\n      isSuperSku\n      parentId\n      roomVOEnabled\n      sampleId\n      __typename\n    }\n    availabilityType {\n      discontinued\n      status\n      type\n      buyable\n      __typename\n    }\n    details {\n      description\n      collection {\n        url\n        collectionId\n        __typename\n      }\n      highlights\n      descriptiveAttributes {\n        name\n        value\n        bulleted\n        sequence\n        __typename\n      }\n      infoAndGuides {\n        name\n        url\n        __typename\n      }\n      installation {\n        leadGenUrl\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    media {\n      images {\n        url\n        type\n        subType\n        sizes\n        __typename\n      }\n      video {\n        shortDescription\n        thumbnail\n        url\n        videoStill\n        link {\n          text\n          url\n          __typename\n        }\n        title\n        type\n        videoId\n        longDescription\n        __typename\n      }\n      threeSixty {\n        id\n        url\n        __typename\n      }\n      augmentedRealityLink {\n        usdz\n        image\n        __typename\n      }\n      richContent {\n        content\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    pricing(storeId: $storeId) {\n      promotion {\n        dates {\n          end\n          start\n          __typename\n        }\n        type\n        description {\n          shortDesc\n          longDesc\n          __typename\n        }\n        dollarOff\n        percentageOff\n        savingsCenter\n        savingsCenterPromos\n        specialBuySavings\n        specialBuyDollarOff\n        specialBuyPercentageOff\n        experienceTag\n        subExperienceTag\n        anchorItemList\n        itemList\n        reward {\n          tiers {\n            minPurchaseAmount\n            minPurchaseQuantity\n            rewardPercent\n            rewardAmountPerOrder\n            rewardAmountPerItem\n            rewardFixedPrice\n            __typename\n          }\n          __typename\n        }\n        __typename\n      }\n      value\n      alternatePriceDisplay\n      alternate {\n        bulk {\n          pricePerUnit\n          thresholdQuantity\n          value\n          __typename\n        }\n        unit {\n          caseUnitOfMeasure\n          unitsOriginalPrice\n          unitsPerCase\n          value\n          __typename\n        }\n        __typename\n      }\n      original\n      mapAboveOriginalPrice\n      message\n      preferredPriceFlag\n      specialBuy\n      unitOfMeasure\n      __typename\n    }\n    reviews {\n      ratingsReviews {\n        averageRating\n        totalReviews\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    seo {\n      seoKeywords\n      seoDescription\n      __typename\n    }\n    specificationGroup @skip(if: $skipSpecificationGroup) {\n      specifications {\n        specName\n        specValue\n        __typename\n      }\n      specTitle\n      __typename\n    }\n    taxonomy {\n      breadCrumbs {\n        label\n        url\n        browseUrl\n        creativeIconUrl\n        deselectUrl\n        dimensionName\n        refinementKey\n        __typename\n      }\n      brandLinkUrl\n      __typename\n    }\n    favoriteDetail {\n      count\n      __typename\n    }\n    sizeAndFitDetail {\n      attributeGroups {\n        attributes {\n          attributeName\n          dimensions\n          __typename\n        }\n        dimensionLabel\n        productType\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    subscription @skip(if: $skipSubscribeAndSave) {\n      defaultfrequency\n      discountPercentage\n      subscriptionEnabled\n      __typename\n    }\n    badges(storeId: $storeId) {\n      label\n      color\n      creativeImageUrl\n      endDate\n      message\n      name\n      timerDuration\n      timer {\n        timeBombThreshold\n        daysLeftThreshold\n        dateDisplayThreshold\n        message\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    keyProductFeatures @skip(if: $skipKPF) {\n      keyProductFeaturesItems {\n        features {\n          name\n          refinementId\n          refinementUrl\n          value\n          __typename\n        }\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    seoDescription\n    installServices {\n      scheduleAMeasure\n      __typename\n    }\n    dataSource\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n"}

    url = 'https://www.homedepot.com/federation-gateway/graphql?opname=productClientOnlyProduct'

    resp = s.post(url,headers=headers,json=query).json()

    name = resp['data']['product']['identifiers']['productLabel']
    price = resp['data']['product']['pricing']['value']
    stock = resp['data']['product']['fulfillment']['fulfillmentOptions'][0]['services'][0]['locations'][0]['inventory']['quantity']
```

Comment: One option is to use [exception handling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#exceptions) to catch the errors. Another is to us `in` to test if the keys are in the dictionary before trying to read the values.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

Use try-except to catch errors:

```
try:
    name = resp['data']['product']['identifiers']['productLabel']
    price = resp['data']['product']['pricing']['value']
    stock = resp['data']['product']['fulfillment']['fulfillmentOptions'][0]['services'][0]['locations'][0]['inventory']['quantity']
except TypeError:
    print("Data not found")
```

Use `get` instead of brackets [] to access the data. That way if something doesn't exist you can replace it with a default value, and for stock, use `next` so you can return a default in case it doesn't exist:

```
product = resp.get('data', dict()).get('product', dict())
name = product.get('identifiers', dict()).get('productLabel', '')
price = product.get('pricing', dict()).get('value', 0)
stock = next((product.get('fulfillment', dict()).get('fulfillmentOptions', dict())), 0) # returns 0 if it doesn't exist
```

Comment: I like the 'get' option. Why do you use 'next' for stock and not for price? Are those just 2 different ways to handle the case where it doesn't exist?

Comment: @JMG656 `get` is for getting values from a dictionary and next is for lists. Considering you tried to access stock with index 0, it's obviously a list, so we use `next` in that case

Comment: Got it. For stock, there is a combination of dictionaries and lists. If I wanted to get all the way to "quantity" would I nest `get` and `next` multiple times?

Comment: Exactly :) just in the case of what I wrote, in the `next` it would be dict() at the end instead of 0 `next((product.get('fulfillment', dict()).get('fulfillmentOptions', dict())), dict())` since it should be a dictionary with additional items in it

Answer (score 0):

You can surround the last three lines where you access fields of the response in a `try/except` block.

```py
try:
    name = resp['data']['product']['identifiers']['productLabel']
    price = resp['data']['product']['pricing']['value']
    stock = resp['data']['product']['fulfillment']['fulfillmentOptions'][0]['services'][0]['locations'][0]['inventory']['quantity']
except TypeError:
    print("error occured")
    continue
```

The `continue` keyword is use to continue with the next iteration, regardless of what would follow later in your code block.

Answer (score 0):

add a line that

```
if prod is None:
    del a [prod]
```

you could also use a try ,

```
except TypeError:
   #what you want to do if type is none
```